# NullInjectorError: No provider for ScrollbarHelper

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

Error:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DatatableComponent ->
>   ScrollbarHelper]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[DatatableComponent -> ScrollbarHelper]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ScrollbarHelper!

CurrentBehaviour: Now, I have entry component, and when i trigger that, the above error happens. My project is with --aot compilation. Any help is appreciable

Comment: Some code or [mcve] would be greatly appreciated. Consider complying with [ask].

Comment: When you have a component among **entryComponents** array make sure you remove all selectors from html for that component. In your case it is DatatableComponent. Check your html files for it's selector.